how to display 2 child divs of a parent div side by side instead of one below the other? No method worked for me
I have this code and the divs keep displaying one on top of the other no matter if the children have inline-block, float or any other property.
What is going on?


#resources {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 4%;
  background: rgba(0, 160, 255, 1);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#woodResource #stoneResource {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
<div id="resources">
  <div id="woodResource">
    <img src="/models/wood.png" id="wood"> 0
  </div>
  <div id="stoneResource">
    <img src="/models/stone.png" id="stone"> 0
  </div>
</div>




I tried every advice and method I could find like inline-block, float but none worked.

Learn about flex and grid perhaps might make it simpler.

1.) Increase the width of the parent so that both children can fit (4% is most likely too narrow for both, depending on the parent or window width)
2.) Use a comma in the selector #woodResource, #stoneResource { ... }. Without that comma (which separates the two selectors) this rule will only apply to #stoneResource as a child of #woodResource.


#resources {
position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
z-index: 1;
display: block;
width: 20%;
background: rgba(0, 160, 255, 1);
color: white;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 0.5em;
border-radius: 10%;
}

#woodResource, #stoneResource {
  display: inline-block;
}
 <div id="resources">
        <div id="woodResource">
            <img src="/models/wood.png" id="wood">
            0
        </div>
        <div id="stoneResource">
            <img src="/models/stone.png" id="stone">
            0
        </div>
    </div>



A hint: If you use display: inline-block for the parent, you won't need to define its width at all, the width will adjust to the contents in this case:


#resources {
display: inline-block;
background: rgba(0, 160, 255, 1);
color: white;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 0.5em;
border-radius: 10%;
}

#woodResource, #stoneResource {
  display: inline-block;
}
<div id="resources">
        <div id="woodResource">
            <img src="/models/wood.png" id="wood">
            0
        </div>
        <div id="stoneResource">
            <img src="/models/stone.png" id="stone">
            0
        </div>
    </div>




I'm resizing the images with the width in the parent, because all the images are different size. I added the comma and moved the width attribute to the children though and it worked, so that it arranged them side by side, but now there is another issue with the parent div taking the whole top part of the screen with its blue box. How to make it so that it only displays the divs in the top left corner? The code is otherwise the same.

Use inline-block on the parent as I wrote, then it will adjust to the width of the children.

I have inline-block in both the parent and the children, yet it still covers the whole top area.
`#resources {
position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
z-index: 1;
display: inline-block;
background: rgba(0, 160, 255, 1);
color: white;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 0.5em;
border-radius: 10%;
}
#woodResource, #stoneResource, #foodResource, #moneyResource {
display: inline-block;
width: 4%;
}`
